# android : cannot change encoding video size & how to encoding h.264

Tags: android, h.264, video-encoding

I have an HTC Desire (Android 2.3.3, API level 9). I am trying to write a program to record 320x240 h.263 video. Without any settings, the code works well and the output resolution is 177x144. But it always crashes when I set the video size. And I find that only android 3.0+ support encoding h.264, I want to know how to do that on android 2.1+? I would be grateful for a solution to either issue. Here is what I am doing and the log

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioChannels(1);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(141000);
recorder.setVideoSize(320,240);
recorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
```

There is the log

```
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546): java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at com.mobvcasting.camcorder.CamcorderView.startRecording(CamcorderView.java:75)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at com.mobvcasting.camcorder.Camcorder.onKeyDown(Camcorder.java:36)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1256)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2102)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1666)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2574)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2549)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1881)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3694)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-11 21:57:32.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) link you cannot do this in 2.1 (only in 3.0+). It simply cannot be done.

Comment: I know that it cannot be done by android's api. But I want to know  whether there is some third party to finish this mission;-)

Answer (score 1):

i've written a small application (on api level 7) to record videos with H264 codec and store them on the sd card.
in my case it was possible to set the H264 codec to the media recorder:

```
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

finally i had copied the recorded file to my laptop and checked the codec with vlc player.
i was still H264 codec at the codec details of vlc.

i've run the applicatoin on a htc desire with android 2.2 (froyo).
i don't know why, but in my oppinion it looks like that android 2.2+ supports h264 encoding.